# Minimum representation of total generalized variation

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations

I need help understanding the proof of Theorem 3.1 from [this paper](http://www.iki.fi/tuomov/mathematics/SampTA2011.pdf). To make this post self-containded, at first I briefly review the definitions.

Let 
 $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded domain and 
$\alpha =(\alpha_0,\, \alpha_1) > 0$. The functional assigning each $u \in L_1(\Omega)$
the
value
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 \text{TGV}^2_{\alpha}(u) = \sup\, \bigg\{\int_{\Omega} u \, \text{div}^2 v\, dx : \, v\in C_c^2 (\Omega, S^{d\times d}),\,&|| v ||_{\infty} \leq \alpha_0,\, \\ &|| \text{div}\, v||_{\infty} \leq \alpha_1 \bigg\} \end{split}\end{equation*}
is called the Total Generalized Variation of second order of $u$.

Here, $S^{d \times d}$ is the set of symmetric matrices, $C_c^2 (\Omega, S^{d\times d})$
is the vector space of compactly supported, twice continuously
differentiable $S^{d \times d}$-valued mappings and $\text{div}\, v \in C_c^1 (\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{d})$  and 
$\text{div}^2 v  \in 
C_c(\Omega)$
are defined by
$$ (\text{div}\, v)_i = \sum_{j=1}^{d} \frac{\partial v_{ij}}{\partial x_j}, \quad 
\text{div}^2v = \sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{\partial^2 v_{ii}}{\partial x_i^2} + 
2\sum_{i<j} \frac{\partial v_{ij}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}.$$

> **Theorem.**
>   Suppose that 
>   $\text{BD}(\Omega)$ denotes the space of vector fields of Bounded Deformation, i.e.,
>   $w\in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ such that the distributional
>   symmetrized derivative
>   $\mathcal{E}w = \frac{1}{2}(\nabla w + \nabla w^T)$ is an 
>   $S^{d \times d}$-valued 
>   Radon measure. Then 
>   $$ \text{TGV}_{\alpha} ^2 (u)= \min_{w \in \text{BD}(\Omega)} \alpha_1 ||\nabla u -w ||_{\mathcal{M}} + 
> \alpha_0 || \mathcal{E}w ||_{\mathcal{M}}.$$
>
> **Proof.**
>   Choosing
>   $X = C_0^2 (\Omega, S^{d\times d})$,
>   $Y = C_0^1 (\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{d})$,
>   $\Lambda = \text{div} \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ 
>   and for $v\in x$, $w\in Y$,
>   $$ F_1(v) = \iota_{||\cdot||_{\infty}\leq \alpha_0} (v), $$
>   $$ F_2(w) = \iota_{||\cdot||_{\infty}\leq \alpha_1}(w) - \int_{\Omega} u \, \text{div} w \, dx. $$
>   By a simple substitution we observe
>   that 
>   $$ \text{TGV}_{\alpha}^2 (u) = -\inf_{v\in X} F_1(v)  + F_2(\Lambda v). $$
>   Furthermore, $Y=^?\bigcup_{\lambda \geq 0} \lambda \big(  \text{dom}(F_1) - \Lambda \text{dom}(F_2)\big)$
>   hence by Fenchel-Rockafellar duality
>   it follows that 
>   $$ \text{TGV}_{\alpha}^2(u)=\min_{w\in Y^*} F_1^*(-\Lambda^*w )
> + F_2^*(w) .$$
>
> Now, $Y^* = C_0^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)^*$
>   can be regarded as a space of distributions
>   and the dual functionals can be written as
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{split}
>  F_1^*(-\Lambda^*w) &=^? \begin{cases}
> \alpha_0 || \mathcal{E}w ||_{\mathcal{M}} & \text{if }w\in\text{BD}(\Omega)\\
> \infty & \text{else},
> \end{cases} \\
> F_2^*(w) &=^? 
> \begin{cases}
> \alpha_1||\nabla u - w||_{\mathcal{M}}
> & \text{if } \nabla u -w \in \mathcal{M}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)\\
> \infty & \text{else}. 
> \end{cases} 
> \end{split}
> \end{equation*}
>   Since $\text{BD}(\Omega) \subset \mathcal{M}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$, the result follows. $\square$

I need help with the three question-marked equalities. 
For the first one, fidgeting in my chair, I can convince myself why $\supseteq$ holds but for the converse inclusion I'm totally blank.

As for the dual functionals, although it has not been mentioned in the paper, $F_1^*$ and $F_2^*$ are most likely meant to be convex conjugates of the corresponding functionals   which are support functionals here, but I can't just figure out why these equalities hold.

Also what exactly is $w^T$ in the statement of the theorem, and how are we allowed to add its gradient to $\nabla w$? Should they be viewd as matrices? Are they even of the same dimension?

Your help is much needed and appreciated!